# How to reduce image palette to specific colors?

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, python-imaging-library, color-palette

I am playing with a program in Python to create cross stitch schemes and need to reduce colors in an image to specific floss colors [like this](http://www.dmc-usa.com/Products/Needlework-Threads/Embroidery-Threads/~/media/Media/Color%20Cards/Thread/ThreadColorCard_page1.ashx). Not necessary to use all the colors from the floss palette.
On Python or Pseudocode.

[Example](http://piccy.info/view3/5283665/73f743d19ad530702081cb2953f47925/orig/)

Custom palette (in PILL/Pillow for example) is not situable. There 256 colors max, but floss palette has around 450 colors and I plan to use multiple color charts from different manufacturers.

Dithering also not situable in cross-stitching.

I think this could be something like:

```
result = []
for pixel_color in image:
    nearest = None
    for floss_color in floss_palette:
        distance = delta_e_cie2000(pixel_color, floss_color)
        if distance < nearest:
            nearest = floss_color
    result.append(nearest)
```

May be there is a faster algorithm? (image_width * image_heigh * colors in palette = 112M delta_e calculations and comparisons on average 500x500px image. It's a lot.)

Dictonary for already calculated delta_e? Another algorithm/aproach/optimization?

Comment: memoize - you don't need to retest colors that you've already done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of memoize. I've also used the builtin `min`

```
def nearest(pixel_color, mem={}):
    if pixel_color in mem:
        return mem[pixel_color]
    n = min(floss_palette, key=lambda fc:delta_e_cie2000(pixel_color, fc))
    mem[pixel_color] = n
    return mem[pixel_color]

result = [nearest(pixel_color) for pixel_color in image]
```

Comment: Looks nice. And then I can do `PIL.Image.putdata(result)`? Does it make sense 1) `available_pixel_color = PIL.Image.getcolors`, 2) Pass `available_pixel_color` to `nearest` to make dictionary, 3) apply this dictionary to `pixel_color` and get final list?

Comment: You can do `result = PIL.Image.eval(image, nearest)` to apply the reduction to all pixels.